# Square ImageView

Tags: java, android

This is good practice, to make square image? Side of the square container is equal to its width.

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView{
    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project needs it - it's good. I did the same thing some time ago and you must remember that sometimes `widthMeasureSpec` or `heightMeasureSpec` can be very small, so I suggest that you check those values, choose the bigger one and then call `super.onMeasure()`.

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      if (widthMeasureSpec < 1) {
          super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
      } else {
          super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
      }
    }
```